# How to update a timestamp field of a mysql table ?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, field

I want to update all the empty logout_time fields into 2011-12-26 14:48:36.

I tried the following query so as to update the logout_time field (timestamp) in the log_details table:

```
update log_details set logout_time='2011-12-26 14:48:36',tab_status='0' 
where logout_time =''
```

It doesn't work. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting when you attempt to run this command? And do you put the ; at the end (I ask because its not in the query you typed here and that always breaks things)

Comment: log_details is the name of the table, logout_time is a timestamp field in the table which stores the logout time of the user. Due to some mistakes the values didnt added as i expected so i have to change the timestamp values wherever it is null to 2011-12-26 14:48:36 manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update log_details set logout_time='2011-12-26 14:48:36',tab_status='0' 
where logout_time IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if those "empty" fields are '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. If it's timestamp most likely that would be the case and not "empty" as null empty. The best way is to check what exactly you have in fields you want to update.

//update

if field is actually NULL then it should be

```
update log_details set logout_time='2011-12-26 14:48:36',tab_status='0' 
where logout_time IS NULL
```

Comment: The timestamp field is actually empty. I want to fill that field with the manual value using a quey. Please tell me how can i do it ? is there any way i can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function in this way :

```
update log_details set logout_time=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-12-26 14:48:36'),tab_status='0' 
where logout_time =''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update log_details set logout_time='2011-12-26 14:48:36',tab_status='0' 

where logout_time ='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

this query should help because the timestamp column empty means '0000-00-00 00:00:00'